# Remove path prefix from unix tree

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, command

I have a requirements in UNIX command
where i have a path similar to this:

```
path/to/file/manyfiles.extensions
```

now i want the output something similar to-

```
file/manyfiles.extensions
```

now i can do this listing both /path/to and /path removing them one by one.

but i might get only "/path/to" as my input and i have to remove both from the tree in one command.

You might think that i can list 2 folders to remove, but in many a cases i get structures having 12-13 of subfolders in which i need only the first and last folder in many cases.

eg - `Source files - target/classes/

Remove prefix - target`

Result:

```
classes/my/code/HelloWorld.class
classes/my/code/HelloWorldImpl.class
classes/my/code/Main.class
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you try explaining it again clearly with some examples.

Comment: Let me make it more simpler -
Suppose you have a address like this -
folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7/file.txt 
now this structure takes too much time to process for my work
i want the structure to be trimmed to something like this
folder6/folder7/file.txt

Comment: So you want last 2 sub-folders and file name in the end?

Comment: posted an answer below.

Answer (score 18):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to strip off some given prefix on a path. Given a declaration `path=/a/path/to/a/directory` and a pattern `*a/` you can strip off the prefix matching that pattern in two ways in Bash:

```
echo ${path#*a/}    # outputs "path/to/a/directory"
echo ${path##*a/}   # outputs "directory"
```

The first variant is non-greedy and stops at the first match, while the second is greedy and stops at the longest possible match for the pattern. The pattern `*a/` occurs twice in out path here, so the results are then different.

In your case the pattern would be something like `path/to` and the path `path/to/file/manyfiles.extensions`, so one of the following would work, depending on whether you need to be greedy or not:

```
path=path/to/file/manyfiles.extensions
path=${path#*path/to/}   # assigns "file/manyfiles.extensions" to $path
```

or

```
path=path/to/file/manyfiles.extensions
path=${path##*path/to/}  # assigns "file/manyfiles.extensions" to $path
```

For reference, read about [Bash parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073).

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to the `basename` command to strip the directories off your filename, combined with the `dirname` command which will give you just the directory structure.

You can then use whatever logic you require to get the parts of the directory you need to keep, and put it back together with the filename.

Something like in this pseudocode:

```
original_file='/some/long/path/to/a/file'
file_name=$(basename $original_file)
dir_name=$(dirname $original_file)

short_dir='...use regex or whatever logic you need to pear ${dir_name} down (we'll need more info to help with this)'

new_file="${short_dir}/${file_name}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `grep -oP`:

```
p="older2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7/file.txt"
s=$(grep -oP '([^/]+/){2}[^/]+/?$' <<< "$p")
echo "$s"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
folder6/folder7/file.txt
```