# Remove prefix, with prefix specified in variable

Tags: bash

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614157/remove-path-prefix-from-unix-tree).

I have this variable:

```
var=/myprefix/something/something-else
```

And this prefix:

```
prefix=/myprefix/
```

I want to remove the `prefix`. We can do this in a non-greedy way as follows:

```
echo ${var#/myprefix/}
```

Which gives:

```
something/something-else
```

as expected. How can I use the `prefix` variable instead of hard-coding the prefix?

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
echo ${var#${prefix}}
```

Here you have [some documentation](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html), and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) the bash manual.